# Rails form above Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-for, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a newsletter subscription from scratch using rails 4 and Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal.

I created a Subscriber model and subscribers controller which contains a 'create' method.

The button which openes the modal has to appear anytime, so I included it in the navbar that is placed in the application.html.erb layout view file.

This is the code I used for the modal: (in views/layout/application.html.erb)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Newsletter Subscriptions</h4>
          </div>
          <% form_tag(controller: 'subscribers', action: 'create') do %>
              <div class="modal-body">              
                    <p><%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] placeholder: "Enter your email address" %></p>             
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <p><%= submit_tag "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>                  
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For some reason it won't show anything in the modal except the title.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `<%= form_tag` instead of `<% form_tag`.
In previous versions of Rails, `<% form_tag` was used I think, but since `form_tag` is outputting html, it should be used with `<%= %>`.